# Dattatreya Stotram transmission

Tags: history, narada

In Dattatreya Stotram Narada had extolled ( नरदेन  प्रकीर्तितम ) the divine qualities of Dattatreya, son of Atri/ Anasuya long long ago.

[Dattatreya Sanskrit Stotram](https://www.devshoppe.com/blogs/articles/shri-dattatreya-stotram-in-sanskrit)

It is believed that in Kali Yuga Dattatreya took births again in the 15th century.

So how did the Stothram directly authored by Narada survive for so long to be handed down to us in our times? Can we assume the kirthans came down in time by popular word of mouth?